# refresh arraylist by another arraylist

Tags: java

I have this code:

```
public class Server{
  public static ArrayList<Server> all;

  public int id;
  public int sid;

  public Server(int id){
    thid.id = id;
    sid = fetchSidFromDB(id);
  }

  public Server(int id, int sid){
    thid.id = id;
    sid = sid;
  }

  public static void loadAll(){
    //Assume that I fill 'all' with the servers from the db
    all = new ArrayList<Server>();
  }

  //gets only a list of 'id's with out the sid
  public static void refreshAll(){
  }
}

//in the main
Server.loadAll();
Server.refreshAll();
```

I want that `refreshAll` will get new list from the db and do:

1. If the `id` isnt in the object already - insert it
2. If the `id` is in the object but the sid isnt the same - replace it
3. If there is an `id` in `all` that isnt in the new list - remove it

This is simple, but as I see it I can only do it with:

```
for(...){
  for(...){
  }
  for(...){
}
```

One inside `for` for step 1&2 and one inside `for` for step 3.

I wonder if there's more efficient way.

Comment: What is stopping you to replace the all List itself with the new list?

Comment: why yo just not replace with the new list ??

Comment: The `sid = fetchSidFromDB(id);` is just an example, it is much more complicated then that, that is what i'm try to avoid from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it more efficient in two ways (not counting the one in Yogendra Singh's comment):

1. Use a `HashMap` with `id` as the key instead. If you need the elements to be in the same order as you received them from the database, use `LinkedHashMap`.
2. If you can make sure the lists are ordered by `id`, you can just use a single loop and advance over the second list with an iterator.

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you are trying to cache database records...for that tasks there are tools already availiable, one of them is `JPA`, which can handle caching transparently

take a look for example on [EclipeLink](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/)